# Get запрос для вконтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток, нужно с помощью GET запроса вконтакте получить заданное или максимально возможное число пользователей вконтакте (их id), например нам нужно получить всех пользователей по данному запросу, а вернее по данным критериям http://vk.com/search?c[age_from]=18&c[age_to]=25&c[country]=1&c[group]=72495085&c[name]=1&c[online]=1&c[section]=people&c[sex]=2, как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

См. [выполнение запросов к api](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests) и метод ВК api [`users.search()`](https://vk.com/dev/users.search).

Получить можно не более 1000 результатов – это ограничение ВК. Параметр `offset` тут не поможет.